# Why does resetting an array after looping through it only work for two complete iterations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a fairly straight forward question.  I want to loop through one array, making sure not to select the same value twice, (for which I used `splice` to move the selected values to a new array) and then, when all values have been selected, start the process over (for which I used `slice` to make a copy, and then clear out the old one. However, for some reason, be it async or what, my technique only works for two loop completions (then the array does not flip). I did try using callbacks but had the same (lack of) success.

Can anyone suggest any reason why this is happening? my code is below, and you can see from the picture that it works correctly for two iterations.

```
var oldArray = [4441, 2444, 2343, 64]; //Beginning array
var oldestArray = []; //"Holder" array

function getItem() {
    var item;
    var index;
    if(!oldArray.length) {
        //Check to see if all values have been selected, then switch arrays
        oldArray = oldestArray.slice();
        oldestArray = [];
        console.log('The arrays have been reset');
    }
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (oldArray.length));
    item = oldArray.splice(index, 1);
    oldestArray.push(item[0]);
    return item;
}

var fun = function() {
    console.log('This is old Array');
    console.log(oldArray);
    console.log('This is oldest Array');
    console.log(oldestArray);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    getItem();
    fun();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you're mixing up functional(ish) and async.

Comment: (Also, what is the *expected* output/contract?)

Comment: What I was hoping / expecting, is that, items are pushed from `oldArray` to `oldestArray` and then once `oldArray` is empty, `oldArray` gets all the values from `oldestArray` and the cycle begins again `oldestArray`

Comment: I am sorry if this seems like a duplicate of my previous question, it is really my attempt to clarify that question (which I would like to delete) because this issue is unrelated to a typo).

Comment: I am not sure why this is a duplicate, I tried to edit the question to reflect that this is a completely different issue that I am having here.

Comment: Adding `console.log(i);` after `fun()` counts from 0 to 24. What were you expecting? There's nothing asynchronous here, it's all sequential.

Comment: When I run this in jsfiddle, the arrays are reset 6 times: http://jsfiddle.net/W7c9C/

Comment: I was expecting that each time the `oldArray` reaches a length 0, because all of its contents have been spliced, that it is "refilled" with the contents of `oldestArray`.   I am only using that loop to show that this works twice, but eventually `oldArray` stays at length 0.

Comment: @Startec That's not what happens when I run it. It runs just like you're saying it should. This seems like browser differences shouldn't affect it, but what browser are using?

Comment: I was testing (and that screen shot was from) fireBug.  You are right, when running in chrome the function runs how I'd hope.  I will keep testing.  I have spent a few hours on this so I really hope it wasn't just a fireBug bug.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really figure out what the Firebug console is doing, but this seems to be an issue with `console.log()`ging a variable that is changing after it's logged. You can see the expected output if you coerce the arrays into strings when you output them:

```
console.log('This is old Array');
console.log("[" + oldArray + "]");
console.log('This is oldest Array');
console.log("[" + oldestArray + "]");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W7c9C/1/